# Strings inside of comments

Tags: string, python-3.x, comments, concatenation

I noticed that when I place quotations around something in a comment line, the words in quotations change color to indicate that the interpreter sees them as a string. I found this confusing because I thought that the interpreter was supposed to ignore comments. I am curious to know if I did something wrong. The code is below.

```
# The output of the concatenation above would be:
# 'spameggs'
```

'spameggs' changes color even though it is part of a comment line.

Answer (score 0):

Its showing me as comment ,No change of color of the text you are mentioning,which editor are you using .Seems like some editor problem.Try to open it in IDLE.IT will be all red color.

Thanks

Comment: For that particular code, I was using Qpython3 on my android device.

Comment: In that case i have not use this qPYTHON3 ,so i don'nt know about it

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in Qpython3 for android. In Liclipse this worked fine, and remained as a comment.